# Accessing JavaScript object via key

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object called data. I am using the following code to sort the keys in the object :

```
var index = [];

// build the index
for (var x in data) {
    index.push(x);
}

// sort the index
index.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a == b ? 0 : (a > b ? 1 : -1);
});
```

I then want to access the value for a particular index key in the following way :

```
for (var i=0; i<index.length; i++) {
    var key = index[i];
    document.getElementById(key).value = data.key;
}
```

However I am getting undefined for the data.key value. Can anyone suggest why ?

Comment: I've edited out the "JSON" term from your question. JSON implies a string: if you can loop it with a `for()` construct, it can't be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
document.getElementById(key).value = data[key];
```

If the key you want to access is stored within a variable, you have to use the bracket notation. In your code, JavaScript will search for a key named "key" and thus fails.

Example:

```
var key = 'test';

console.log( data.key );  // yields content of data.key
console.log( data[key] ); // yields content of data.test
```

Comment: To clarify: the `document` object is part of the DOM so it's used to manipulate HTML documents, not JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Object.keys(data)[key] ?
```

Not sure it would work, without showing the structure of data.

edit: This way retrieves object key according to numerical index (0,1...,n), and not by name.